# Are C preprocessor statements a part of the C language?

Tags: c, standards, c99, c-preprocessor

I recall a claim made by one of my professors in an introductory C course. He stated that the `#define` preprocessor command enables a programmer to create a constant for use in later code, and that the command was a **part of the C language**.

```
/* Is this truly C code? */
#define FOO 42
```

Since this was in an introductory programming class, I suspect that he was merely simplifying the relationship between the source file and the compiler, but nevertheless I wish to verify my understanding.

Are preprocessor statements completely independent from the C language (dependent on the specific compiler used) or are they explicitly described in the **C99 standard**? Out of curiosity, did K&R ever mention preprocessor macros?

Comment: See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Comment: (I had an earlier draft of what @denull found.) However, the preprocessor is available separately from the compiler in some environments, and some languages can use it indirectly.  There is a Perl module to invoke the C preprocessor as a filter on a Perl file.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that "the" C standard/language is now C11 (this is the version in devnull's link). C99 is one behind. Better for compatibility of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the standard describes the preprocessor. It's a standardized part of the C language.

Note that `#include`, which is essential for modularization of code, is a preprocessor directive.

In the [publically-available draft of the C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), the preprocessor is described in section 6.10.

Comment: is GCC's preprocessor implementation a superset of the standard, or does it adhere strictly?

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor is indeed part of the C and C++ standard (chapter 16 in the C++ standard) and the standards describe how the preprocessor and the language interact (for example it is illegal to re-`#define` the C keywords).

However the C preprocessor can work with other languages than C for any kind of simple file preprocessing (I have seen it used with LaTeX files for example).

Comment: It is not illegal to `#define` a C keyword, provided that the definition is not in effect when you `#include` a standard header, or use a macro from a standard header (7.1.2p4). The second prohibition is a bit complicated to comply with, since almost all standard library names can be implemented with macros, but it is possible with a bit of work. (For example, it is legal to #undefine macros corresponding to standard library functions.) Sorry for adding this comment after so many years; I was lead to this answer by a comment from another question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the preprocessor ***is*** part of the C language. Conceptually it is ran before the source is compiled.

Along with constant definitions, the preprocessor is used to implement two very important constructs:

1. `#include` which brings other files into the compilation unit.
2. *include guards*; i.e. the pattern,

   ```
   #if !defined(METAWORD)
   #define METAWORD 1
   /* struct definition, function prototype */
   #endif
   ```

Out of interest, these two usages have survived into C++, constant definition can be implemented in other (better?) ways.